# ssh - alternative to copy with cp

Tags: ssh, copy

I want to copy a file with spaces. For example "file 1.jpg".
I want to do it from a putty-ssh session. 
cp doenst work because of the spaces. Is there another way to do it? 
Destination is a network share.

Thanks for your kindly assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cp` doesn't care about spaces: it is the shell that does, when it parses the command line parameters. An alternative program would have the exact same problem.

Use quotes or escape the spaces. For example;

```
$ cp "with spaces" nospaces

$ cp with\ spaces nospaces
```

Comment: Thx! Can you also tell me about the destination? Under windows it is \\server\share. But what does it look like on linux in this command?

Comment: @fuuman Generally `/mnt/server-share`, where such has been previously mounted. The context is unclear (and it should be in a different question, and likely over on Super User).

Comment: You may need to look at `smbmount` to mount / view the windows SMB/CIFS share in linux. `smbclient` may also be helpful for troubleshooting.